How can we limit ansible on "VMs" when running on a hypervisor?
I'm new to Ansible, and I'm trying to figure out how I could, use the --limit parameter, but for specific VMs and not the hypervisor/host itself.
I explain myself: I have some roles that I use on a Proxmox hypervisor. Like Deploy-vms, Erase-vms, Snapshop-VM, ... But I would like to have a simple way to say, redeploy only the VM20 and VM21 for example.
As playbooks are running on the hypervisor and not on the VMs, the issue is that commands like ansible-playbook -i proxmox.yaml playbook-deploy-vms.yml --limit 'vm20,vm21' are not going to work, as the only host available is the Proxmox node itself. Second step it will rollback the VM. (I'm trying to limit the rollback to a specific subset of VMs)
Is there any way to achieve this without adding to each task a when clauses ?
Here it is the proxmox.yaml file :
all:
  vars:
    ansible_user: root

pve:
  hosts:
    pve.domain.local


this is the task I have in the role Restore for example. It will get all the VMs from the hypervisor and register a variable used for the next step.
---
- name: List all VMs on {{ node }}
  community.general.proxmox_vm_info:
    api_user: "{{ api_user }}"
    api_token_id: "{{ api_token_id }}"
    api_token_secret: "{{ api_token_secret }}"
    api_host: "{{ api_host }}"
    node: "{{ node }}"
  register: vms

- name: Rollback VMs from snapshot
  community.general.proxmox_snap:
    api_user: "{{ api_user }}"
    api_token_id: "{{ api_token_id }}"
    api_token_secret: "{{ api_token_secret }}"
    api_host: "{{ api_host }}"
    vmid: "{{ item.vmid }}"
    state: rollback
    snapname: OriginalVersion
  loop: "{{ vms.proxmox_vms }}"

the playbook is defined that way :
---
- name: Restore VMs
  hosts: pve   # Here we use the proxmox hypervisor node
  roles:
    - restore-vms



What exactly do you call "targets"? 2) Please edit your question and add a sample of your inventory and playbook code so we can understand your task correctly.


Thanks @AlexanderPletnev, I added some details and files

Q: "Redeploy only the VM20 and VM21."
A: You can use the parameter --limit to hosts from the inventory. In the case you describe, the VMs are not in the inventory. They are listed in the registered variable vms. Let's take the example from the doc and fit it to our case

vms:
  proxmox_vms:
  - {cpu: 0.258944410905281, cpus: 1, disk: 0, diskread: 0, diskwrite: 0, id: qemu/100,
    maxcpu: 1, maxdisk: 34359738368, maxmem: 4294967296, mem: 35158379, name: pxe.home.arpa,
    netin: 99715803, netout: 14237835, node: pve, pid: 1947197, status: running, template: false,
    type: qemu, uptime: 135530, vmid: 100}
  - {cpu: 0, cpus: 1, disk: 0, diskread: 0, diskwrite: 0, id: qemu/101, maxcpu: 1, maxdisk: 0,
    maxmem: 536870912, mem: 0, name: vm20, netin: 0, netout: 0, node: pve, status: stopped,
    template: false, type: qemu, uptime: 0, vmid: 101}
  - {cpu: 0, cpus: 1, disk: 0, diskread: 0, diskwrite: 0, id: qemu/102, maxcpu: 1, maxdisk: 0,
    maxmem: 536870912, mem: 0, name: vm21, netin: 0, netout: 0, node: pve, status: stopped,
    template: false, type: qemu, uptime: 0, vmid: 101}




There are three VMs in the above example: pxe.home.arpa, vm20, and vm21. You'll have to provide a variable with selected(limited) VMs. For example, let's put them into a comma-separated string that can be easily used on the command line and convert it to a YAML list
limit: vm20,vm21
limit_list: "{{ limit | d('') | split(',') | map('trim') }}"

Then use the filter selectattr and iterate the selected VMs only. For example,
    - debug:
        msg: "Redeploy {{ item.name }} {{ item.id }}"
      loop: "{{ vms.proxmox_vms | selectattr('name', 'in', limit_list) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"

gives
ok: [localhost] => (item=vm20) => 
  msg: Redeploy vm20 qemu/101
ok: [localhost] => (item=vm21) => 
  msg: Redeploy vm21 qemu/102

In your case, there will be the hypervisor instead of the localhost. The debug task demonstrates the idea. Fit it to your needs.


Example of a complete playbook only
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    vms:
      proxmox_vms:
      - {cpu: 0.258944410905281, cpus: 1, disk: 0, diskread: 0, diskwrite: 0, id: qemu/100,
        maxcpu: 1, maxdisk: 34359738368, maxmem: 4294967296, mem: 35158379, name: pxe.home.arpa,
        netin: 99715803, netout: 14237835, node: pve, pid: 1947197, status: running, template: false,
        type: qemu, uptime: 135530, vmid: 100}
      - {cpu: 0, cpus: 1, disk: 0, diskread: 0, diskwrite: 0, id: qemu/101, maxcpu: 1, maxdisk: 0,
        maxmem: 536870912, mem: 0, name: vm20, netin: 0, netout: 0, node: pve, status: stopped,
        template: false, type: qemu, uptime: 0, vmid: 101}
      - {cpu: 0, cpus: 1, disk: 0, diskread: 0, diskwrite: 0, id: qemu/102, maxcpu: 1, maxdisk: 0,
        maxmem: 536870912, mem: 0, name: vm21, netin: 0, netout: 0, node: pve, status: stopped,
        template: false, type: qemu, uptime: 0, vmid: 101}

    limit_list: "{{ limit | d('') | split(',') | map('trim') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: vms.proxmox_vms | to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: limit_list | to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "Redeploy {{ item.name }} {{ item.id }}"
      loop: "{{ vms.proxmox_vms | selectattr('name', 'in', limit_list) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"

If you run the play without the variable limit defined the loop will skip the empty list. Declare the variable limit on the command line. For example, the command below gives the result mentioned above
shell> ansible-playbook pb.ym -e limit=vm20,vm21


